# Using workflow with webform for moderation

Tags: webforms, workflows

I'm working with a Drupal7 site, it currently has both webforms and workflow modules. I need to move a webform from request to approve stages.

I defined the stages, & Created a trigger for the workflow. Asigned permissions and mapped workflow to content type.

I'm sending myself approval requests for testing, and once I get the email with the request link I open it but can't edit the workflow state ( It's shown as Workflow current state: none ) , no "change state" link or button... Is it possible to get these two modules working as I intended? If so, what am I missing?